# RegExp não pega o valor do input

Tags: php, html, regex

Preciso extrair o valor de uma tag `html`

```
<input value="2530317385" name="X-Tmx-session-id" id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden">
```

Estou usando uma `Expressão Regular` para retornar o valor do `input`

```
   $pattern = '~<input type=hidden id=X-Tmx-session-id name=X-Tmx-session-id value=(.*?) \/>~';
   preg_match($pattern, $get, $xArray);
   var_dump($xArray);
```

só que a minha expressão retorna apenas um array vazio: `array(0) { }`

Preciso pegar apenas o `value` do `input`

> 2530317385

Comment: Você apenas retornoar o `value` desse input? `$_GET/$_POST` não resolve isso?

Comment: A Variável $get ela recebe o html que vem do cuRL

Comment: @LucasCasterlamar o teu ultimo edit deformou a pergunta. Restaurei a pergunta. Se quiseres podes apagar a pergunta ou pedir ajuda a um dos moderadores para apagar. Se tiveres duvidas comenta aqui ou no meta (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) que nós ajudamos.

Comment: @Sergio eu não entendi o porque ele copiou o código da resposta e colocou na pergunta, acho que ele não entendeu como funciona o Stackoverflow. Rollback to Revision 3. Lucas somos uma comunidade de perguntas e respostas, se o código da resposta não funcionou você pode comentar falando o problema na propria resposta.

Answer (score 3):

O teu RegEx é diferente do teu html-input, só comparar:

```
 <input value="2530317385" name="X-Tmx-session-id" id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden">
~<input type=hidden id=X-Tmx-session-id name=X-Tmx-session-id value=(.*?) \/>~
```

Falta as aspas, a posição solicitada pelo RegEx é diferente.

Se você está recebendo um html por `curl`, porque não usa o DOM para pegar os elementos? Por exemplo:

```
$get = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input value="test1">
<input value="test2">
<input value="test3">
</body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($get); //O @ previne mostrar erro de HTML

$allInputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach ($allInputs as $input) {
    echo $input->getAttribute('value'), '<br>';
}
```

Ou com XPath (acaso necessite de seletores mais avançados):

```
<?php
$get = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input value="2530317381" name="X-Tmx-session-id" id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden">
    <input value="2530317382" name="X-Tmx-session-id" id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden">
    <input value="2530317383" name="X-Tmx-session-id" id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden">
    <input value="2530317384" name="X-Tmx-session-id" id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden">
</body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($get);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$doc = NULL;

$allInputs = $xpath->query('*/input[@id=\'X-Tmx-session-id\']');

foreach ($allInputs as $input) {
    echo $input->getAttribute('value'), '<br>';
}
```

Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/i9ZCsg

Comment: Os dois exemplo me retorno erro $allInputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

$allInputs = $xpath->query('*/input[@value]');

Comment: @LucasCasterlamar que erro?

Comment: COm Xpath ele não me retorna nada na tela.

Comment: e no primeiro 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /

nessa linha $allInputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

Comment: @LucasCasterlamar corrigido os dois códigos e adicionado exemplo com XPath :)

Comment: Vou edita minha pergunta com o código que usei e seguindo o seu exemplo

Comment: @LucasCasterlamar a minha resposta resolveu o teu problema? Se sim marque a resposta como correta, se não comente o que falhou. Se não entendeu como o StackOverflow funciona, faça um tour (você ganha uma medalha só por fazer isto rs): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Eu também recomendo a utilização da biblioteca DOM contudo prefiro utilizar [esta](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Agora caso queira ratomar a tentativa por `ER`, tente:

#### Exemplo

```
$id = 'X-Tmx-session-id';

$pattern = "~(?=<input.*id=['\"]*{$id}['\"]*.*)<input.*value=['\"]*([^'\"]*)['\"]*.*~";

$get = '<input value="2530317385" name="X-Tmx-session-id" id="X-Tmx-session-id" type="hidden">';

preg_match($pattern, $get, $xArray);

echo "<pre/>";
var_dump($xArray[1]);
```