# Pega name via regex

Tags: php

Como posso pegar o nome dessa `input` via regex(`preg_match_all`) ?

```
<input type="hidden" name="84a99a062288829a0f72271afea83ee9" value="_nc" />
```

Comment: `preg_match_all('/<input[^>*]*name="(.*?)"[^*]*value="_nc"[^*]*>/', $html, $result); var_dump($result);`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr `DOMDocument` abre portas :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Concordo, inclusive uso em [algumas situações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277387/99718), mas a depender do caso, com um simples *regex* deixa o código limpo.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr nem tanto, ainda mais se for pra comparar 6/7 linhas com 4 linhas (contando preg_match + if + var).

Comment: Vão com calma aí, c0d3rs. kkkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o melhor caminho seja usar `DOMDocument` do PHP, que é propriamente para trabalhar com HTML, exemplo:

```
$get = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="84a99a062288829a0f72271afea83ee9" value="_nc" />
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
<input type="hidden" name="baz" value="boo" />
<input type="hidden" name="foobar" value="bazbar" />
</body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($get);

$allInputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');
foreach ($allInputs as $input) {
    echo $input->getAttribute('name'), '<br>';
}
```

Caso queira pegar somente do elemento que tem o valor `_nc`, faça um if:

```
$valor = null;    
$allInputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');

foreach ($allInputs as $input) {
    if ($input->getAttribute('value') == '_nc') {
        $valor = $input->getAttribute('name'), '<br>';
    }
}

echo 'Valor do input:', $valor;
```

Ou use `DOMXpath`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($get);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$valor = null;
$allInputs = $xpath->query("*/input[@value='_nc']");

foreach ($allInputs as $input) {
    $valor = $input->getAttribute('name'), '<br>';
}

echo 'Valor do input:', $valor;
```

Semelhante ao que eu respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59526/3635

Answer (score 0):

Use o match **(?:name=)\"(\w*)\"** e pegue o primeiro grupo.